# General Mathematical Help

Tags: soft-question, self-learning

I'm a $10^{th}$ grade student and I love studying Mathematics by myself. In fact, I understand Mathematical concepts better if I learn them on my own, maybe because then I have time to explore the topic by myself instead of just solving questions by applying the given formulae. And this way, I end up deriving some really helpful formulae before they come up in the chapter and also some useful tricks to solve the questions.

The only problem I face is *forgetting* some concepts sometimes when not practiced or discussed about for a long time (I face this in Science too).

I started $11^{th}$ grade Mathematics a little longer than about a month ago after completing two $10^{th}$ grade Mathematics textbooks. About a week ago, I revisited some problems related to 10th grade Maths (like some questions related to Arithmetic Progressions, Number Theory and the cross multiplication method for solving linear equations in two variables) and faced some problem when solving them. I mean, my skill level in that particular topic seemed to have degraded. I have experienced this quite a few times. Every single time, the reason happens to be **lack of practice** or **not paying enough attention when learning**.

I have gotten over the problem of *not paying enough attention when learning* from the time I started $11^{th}$ grade Maths.

I started solving some workbooks to get rid of the *lack of practice* problem. But most of the times, I am more interested in learning new concepts rather than practicing the earlier learnt concepts. I also feel like I have very little time and a lot of topics to learn and that I'm kind of wasting my time by practicing the same types of questions again and again.

What should I do? A lot of sources suggest teaching and posting my notes online.I think my notes are good and might genuinely help some children my age, too.

I would love to do that on a website that suppports LaTex (because it's fun to write). Please let me know about the website as well

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Practise. I like your idea of writing. You could start a blog. Use MathJax for the math. Check out Paul’s Online Math Notes and Physics Hypertextbook for ideas of what’s been done.

Comment: Thanks! Will do...

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about learning and practice as if they're completely different things. But practice **is** learning, and in fact, is the most important kind. You are forgetting certain concepts because you did not understand them well enough, which is because you didn't *practice* them enough.

Mathematics is a subject that requires deep concentration and thought. You won't get anywhere if you don't pay attention and focus.

Comment: Thanks! And, are you aware of some website for sharing notes with LaTeX?

Comment: Personally I use [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/) but I believe [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/) is more popular.

Comment: Thanks, again! ${}$